# ios - transfer In App Purchase downloaded file to Document folder

Tags: ios, download, in-app-purchase, nsdocumentdirectory

I successfully test my in app purchase function and downloaded the content. However I am not sure of an right way to transfer it to Document folder. I tested with the code:

```
    -(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedDownloads:(NSArray *)downloads
    {
        for (SKDownload *download in downloads)
        {
            switch (download.downloadState) {
                case SKDownloadStateActive:
                    NSLog(@"Download progress = %f",
                          download.progress);
                    NSLog(@"Download time = %f",
                          download.timeRemaining);
                    break;
                case SKDownloadStateFinished:

                    [self downloadFromURL:download.contentURL];///<--This is the function.
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

 -(void)downloadFromURL: (NSURL *) temporaryURL {

        NSString *folderName = [[temporaryURL path] lastPathComponent];
        NSArray *pathArr = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *folder = [pathArr objectAtIndex:0];

        NSString *filePath = [folder stringByAppendingPathComponent:folderName];
        NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];

        NSError *writeError = nil;
        NSData *downloadData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:temporaryURL];
        [downloadData writeToURL: fileURL options:0 error:&writeError];

        if( writeError) {
            NSLog(@"Error in writing file %@' : \n %@ ", filePath , writeError);
            return;
        }
        NSLog(@"File successfully downloaded. Url is %@",fileURL.absoluteString);
        //myFileURL = fileURL;

        NSFileManager *filemgr;
        NSArray *filelist;
        int count;
        int i;

        filemgr =[NSFileManager defaultManager];
        filelist = [filemgr contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:folder error:NULL];
        count = [filelist count];
        NSLog(@"file count %i",count);
        for (i = 0; i < count; i++)
            NSLog(@"%@", filelist[i]);
    }
```

I get a `@"File successfully downloaded. Url is %@"` from the code above but `NSLog(@"%@", filelist[i]);` give me no content. What else is missing here? I found out about [this link](http://xinsight.ca/blog/iap-content-download-in-ios6/)
but not sure how to incorporate into my code. Any pointer will be good.

Comment: `writeToURL:options:error:` returns a BOOL, check that before using the error. Is it file path what you expected?

Answer (score 0):

Let's check:

```
  -(void)downloadFromURL: (NSURL *) temporaryURL {
      // at this time, file is downloaded successfully???
      // I think you should check here
      NSURL * temporaryURL;
      NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
      BOOL existed = [fm fileExistsAtPath:temporaryURL.path];
      if(existed) // file is existed 
      else        // file is not existed == maybe download fails
  }
```

Comment: I tried your code. Still the same result. the console give me `"File successful..."` and the folder still have nothing.